# using sed in a tcl file

Tags: sed, tcl

Hi I am new tcl and have faced the issue like below.

In this code, I was trying to get only line 1 and 2 from a file and want to put them into another variable. But this code didn't work for me.

```
set sed_com "${line1},${line2}p";               # the value of this sed command is 1,2p
set tmp  [exec sh -c {sed -n "${sed_com}" file.tmp | tail -n 1}]; # this one won't work 
set tmp  [exec sh -c {sed -n "1,2p" file.tmp | tail -n 1}];       # this one will work
```

I was wondering if there is a way that we could make the tcl file interpret it like the line 3?

Comment: The reason is that `{braces}` prevent variable substitution (just like single quotes in the shell).

Comment: So you mean if I eliminate the outmost {brace}, it will work?

Comment: Why not just read the lines directly from tcl?

Comment: No, the argument to `-c` must be quoted. Refer to @scheltebron's command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you complicating things by throwing in the `sh -c`? You can just do:

```
set tmp [exec sed -n $sed_com file.tmp | tail -n 1]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. This works for me. But I would like to know that what is the difference between directly run it using exec and throw it in to sh -c?

Comment: By throwing in `sh -c`, you start another shell to run the command for you. That other shell has its own quoting rules, which makes it harder to build the command line in Tcl. It is possible, but can get messy quite quickly: `set tmp [exec sh -c "sed -n '$sed_com' file.tmp | tail -n 1"]`

Comment: @Shang If you're building up a command to feed into `sh -c`, you have to use shell syntax within it. Which is… different to Tcl. There are a few cases where you need it, but most simple pipeline running is best done directly as in the answer. And for picking a range of lines, I'd do that directly in Tcl with no subprocesses at all.